# CSS Transition with filter breaks clipping path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

*Browser: Chrome 60*

**TLDR: ** It seems that using a transition with a filter on a child of a `div` with a clipping path applied causes strange behavior (take a look at the live code example and the pictures). However, this only happens when the background child has a `blur` filter on it too.

I am trying to create a scroll triggered animation using jQuery and CSS transitions. I have two `div`s on the page: a fixed div on the left side with a slanted edge (made using clipping path), and a right div containing content:

[image: Working clipping path]

When the page detects that the user scrolls past a certain point in the page, it will add a class to the text in the left `div`, making it blur out. This all works fine, until I add `transition: filter 0.5s;` to the text - this causes the clipping path to break (randomly jumps up by around `100px`) while the transition is occuring:

[image: Broken clipping path]

Take a look at a live example (code included):

https://codepen.io/sunnylan/full/eEWKYX

I have tried to isolate where the problem comes from, but I am having trouble, since it seems as if a combination of multiple elements are causing the problem. For example, the problem disappears when I remove the clipping path. It also goes away when I remove the transitions from the navigation list items. More specifically, here are the problem areas (removing any of them will fix the problem):

Adding a clipping path to the sidebar

```
clip-path: polygon( // line 191
              0 0,
              100% 0,
              100% - $sidebar-angle 100%,
              0 100%);
```

Adding a blur filter to the sidebar background:

```
filter: blur(20px); //line 201
```

Adding a transition to the nav items:

```
transition: filter $animation-speed ease, opacity $animation-speed ease; // line 222
```

Comment: looks like not only a trouble in chrome, for the clip-path  firefox is fine but   it has issue with title being jumpy :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a tricky one. Looks like it's something specific to Chrome, seeing as FF works OK minus a few oddities.

It looks like the specific cause to the problem is animating the `nav-bar` when the `selected` class is applied to it. If you don't do that then the clip-path animates correctly, but then there's no opacity/blur animation. You can see that when the `selected` class is applied, the clip-path messes up for the duration of the transition, and then goes the way you want when it's done. I'm guessing this is rendering from the innermost child outwards.

The fix, is to separate the two, instead of nesting them.

```js
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
        d = $(document).height(),
        c = $(window).height();
    var percent = s.map(0, d - c, 0, 100);
    if (percent > 15) {
      $('.nav-bar-wrapper .nav-bar').css('top', s.map(0, d - c, 10, -10) + '%');
      $('.sidebar').addClass('closed');
      $('.nav-bar-wrapper').addClass('closed');
      $('.nav-item').addClass('selected');
    } else {
      $('.nav-bar-wrapper .nav-bar').css('top', '40%');
      $('.sidebar').removeClass('closed');
      $('.nav-bar-wrapper').removeClass('closed');
      $('.nav-item').removeClass('selected');
    }
  });
```

```css
.sidebar {
  background: black;

  //fix on left side of page
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  //initial width
  width: $sidebar-open;

  //make slanted edge
  clip-path: polygon(
                  0 0,
                  100% 0,
                  100% - $sidebar-angle 100%,
                  0 100%);

  //background picture layer
  .background {
    @include fill-parent-bg;
    background-image: url('/img/cb-colour-nightsky.jpg');
    filter: blur(20px);
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  //center sliding nav bar
  @include flex;
  justify-content: center;

  //animate it!
  transition: width $animation-speed ease;

  &.closed {
    width: $sidebar-closed;
  }
}

//moving component
.nav-bar-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: $sidebar-open;
  transition: width $animation-speed ease;
  
  &.closed {
    width: $sidebar-closed;
  }
  
  .nav-bar {
    background: gray;
    //keep component where it is, unless modified by jQuery
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%; //default vertical position
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);

    //animate it!
    transition: top $animation-speed ease;

    .nav-item {
      //fade in/out animations
      transition: filter $animation-speed ease, opacity $animation-speed ease;
      filter: blur(15px);
      opacity: 0.5;
      &.selected {
        opacity: 1;
        filter: blur(0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar background"></div>
<div class="nav-bar-wrapper">
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <h1 class="nav-item" style="color:white; height: 100px;">Test content</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's your CodePen modified: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZVBNJ

With this, though, it looks like for a moment the text gets rendered twice, even though it's only on there once. Again, this is a Chrome-specific issue.

Comment: Many thanks! I'm pretty new to frontend/design, it kind of annoys me to have a bunch of wrapper divs and stuff - I guess it doesn't matter too much, as long as it works

Comment: Yeah, it can be annoying. When you have a lot of them things can be hard to follow sometimes. In this case, I used it as a "mock" version of how you were using the sidebar element before. Really only for sizing and placement, then the `.nav-bar` element inside of that is positioned relative to the wrapper. I did it that way in case you have more than one nav-bar element. You can throw it in the wrapper and it should align, more or less, correctly. (you might have to go from pos:abs to flex though) @AJC

Comment: Sorry to bother you again - There seems to be another problem - if I animate the scale of `nav-item`, it causes `background` to scale as well

Comment: @AJC Hmm, could you throw it in a CodePen? When I try to add `transform: scale(2, 2)` to `.nav-item` with the animation transition, it seems to work as expected (not relative to parent, as scale does). Here's an updated codpen showing what I tried: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKKWGa

Comment: @AJC if I understand right, you only want the img to move upwards, but it is also growing width-wise. The reason this is happening is because you have `background-size: cover` applied to the `.background` element. (see line 243). If you remove that, you will get a parallax like effect, without the width scaling. If I've misunderstood let me know, I love to help. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMqQra

Comment: yup, that was exactly what I wanted. Thanks again!